# 400 Error: Bad request AutoDesk Forge Api

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I was following a GitHub sample project for AutoDesk Forge at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-nodejs-tutorial  and they said to implement Model Derivative uploader before implementing the viewer.  I tried this GitHub project- https://github.com/jaimerosales/modelderivative-nodejs-tutorial
As per their instructions I need to mention client id , secret key, and bucket name. And the running it, I am getting a 400 error.

```
**** Getting bucket details :  
nikhil7j9ug4pgfj7lcukyoht8salipyb7skfc7j9ug4pgfj7lcukyoht8salipyb7skfc
**** Getting all buckets ****
**** Uploading to 


bucket:nikhil7j9ug4pgfj7lcukyoht8salipyb7skfc7j9ug4pgfj7lcukyoht8salipyb7skfc 
File:./models/House.dwfx
**** Get all buckets response:
BUCKETS::::  extract-autodesk-io-20177j9ug4pgfj7lcukyoht8salipyb7skfc
BUCKETS::::  model2017-11-24-06-00-57-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
BUCKETS::::  model2017-11-24-06-01-25-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
BUCKETS::::  model2017-11-24-06-01-57-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
BUCKETS::::  model2017-11-24-06-02-10-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
BUCKETS::::  nikhil7j9ug4pgfj7lcukyoht8salipyb7skfc
BUCKETS::::  
nikhil7j9ug4pgfj7lcukyoht8salipyb7skfc7j9ug4pgfj7lcukyoht8salipyb7skfc
BUCKETS::::  testname7j9ug4pgfj7lcukyoht8salipyb7skfc
error: sdaflksofk { statusCode: 400, statusMessage: 'Bad Request' }
{ statusCode: 400, statusMessage: 'Bad Request' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to debug into the app to see if you can find out more about why you are running into this problem?

You could also try my sample app to create your own bucket and upload a file into it: [OSS Manager](https://oss-manager.herokuapp.com)
Source code: [OSS Manager Source Code](https://github.com/adamenagy/oss.manager-nodejs).

When you are viewing a file with this sample the URN will be shown in the Browser's Console Window

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I ran your live app and getting an error. https://pasteboard.co/GVAkCyP.png   .

Comment: When I debugged your code, I am getting same unauthorized error using ,y client id and secret!! Actually What is happening :(  ( log out : https://pasteboard.co/GVAxtkl.png )

Comment: Have you enabled "Model Derivative API" for your app? Click on your app in developer.autodesk.com and check what's listed in the top under "APIs"

Comment: I have only 2 Apis BIM360 and Data management API. I cant find others. Even there is no other api when I tried to create one!. Please find in the screenshot at https://pasteboard.co/GVGsjvv.png

Comment: Thank You!  I was running a basic account. I switched it to Trial and got all APIs.